# passing values from unity 3D to objective c file

Tags: ios, objective-c, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia

My app has two windows. First one is unity 3D exported to ios which uses vuforia kit for doing augmnted reality. Second is native xcode files. I need to pass a string value from unity to native objective c file because I need to display some values based on that. I'm using xcode 7 and unity 5. Please help me understand how to do it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you tried the solution provided by the answer ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with the native plugin support in Unity. You need to import the native method into a class and call it via another method. You can find more documentation on it here: http://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/NativePlugins.html

Here is a really simple code example that should fit your needs.
The C# class:

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public static class SomeScript
{
    [DllImport("__Internal")]
    private static extern void _NativeMethodName(string stringValue);

    public static void PassStringValue(string stringValue)
    {
         _NativeMethodName(stringValue);
    }
}
```

And the native plugin code:

```
extern "C" {
    void _NativeMethodName(const char* stringValue)
    {
        NSLog(@"Passed string value: %s", stringValue);
    }
}
```

Comment: how do you pass arrays (e.g. of strings) from Objective-C to C#?